# Scala: decrement for-loop

Tags: list, scala, for-loop

I noticed that the following two for-loop cases behave differently sometimes while most of the time they are the same. I couldn't figure out the pattern, does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

case 1:

```
 for (i <- myList.length - 1 to 0 by -1) { ... }
```

case 2:

```
for (i <- myList.length - 1 to 0) { ...}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what's "different" or "the same" and what values of `myList` produces those conditions?

Comment: case 2 seems to work fine for most situations. But I just ran into a scenario that myList has 10 elements and it didn't go through the for-loop at all. But this 10 elements myList works fine with case 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they definitely don't do the same things.  `n to 0 by -1` means "start at `n` and go to 0, counting *backwards* by 1.  So:

```
5 to 0 by -1
// res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
```

Whereas `n to 0` means "start at `n` and got to 0 counting *forward* by 1".  But you'll notice that if `n > 0`, then there will be nothing in that list, since there is no way to count *forward* to 0 from anything greater than zero.

```
5 to 0
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range()
```

The only way that they would produce the same result is if `n=0` since counting from 0 to 0 is the same forwards and backwards:

```
0 to 0 by -1   // Range(0)
0 to 0         // Range(0)
```

In your case, since you're starting at `myList.length - 1`, they will produce the same result when the length of `myList` is 1.

In summary, the first version makes sense, because you want to count down to 0 by counting backward (`by -1`).  And the second version doesn't make sense because you're not going to want to count *forward* to 0 from a length (which is necessarily non-negative).

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to learn more about how value members `to` and `by` works.

`to` - Click [Here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int@to(end:Int,step:Int):scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive) for API documentation
`to` is a value member that appears in classes like int, double etc.

```
scala> 1 to 3
res35: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3)
```

Honestly, you don't have to use `start to end by step` and start.to(end, step) will also work if you are more comfortable working with in this world. Basically, `to` will return you a Range.Inclusive object if we are talking about integer inputs.

---

`by` - Click [Here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range@by(step:Int):scala.collection.immutable.Range) for API documentation

> Create a new range with the start and end values of this range and a new step

```
scala> Range(1,8) by 3
res54: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(1, 4, 7)
scala> Range(1,8).by(3)
res55: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(1, 4, 7)
```

---

In the end, lets spend some time looking at what happens when the step is on a different direction from start to end. Like `1 to 3 by -1`

Here is the source code of the Range class and it is actually pretty straightforward to read:

```
def by(step: Int): Range = copy(start, end, step)
```

So `by` is actually calling a function `copy`, so what is copy?

```
protected def copy(start: Int, end: Int, step: Int): Range = new Range(start, end, step)
```

So `copy` is literally recreate a new range with different step, then lets look at the constructor or Range itself.

Reading this paragraph of code

```
  override final val isEmpty = (
       (start > end && step > 0)
    || (start < end && step < 0)
    || (start == end && !isInclusive)
  )
```

These cases will trigger the exception and your result will be a empty Range in cases like `1 to 3 by -1`..etc.

Sorry the length of my post is getting out of control since I am also learning Scala now.
Why don't you just read the source code of [Range](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/27da46343cd545534819300235bc64ab74958c92/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Range.scala), it is written by Martin Odersky and it is only 500 lines including comments :)